# Como poderia criar uma função em javascript que receba os dados desse script em html? informado e a idade (em anos e meses)

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

com base nesse script:

```
<h2>Qual sua data de nascimento?</h2>
<input type="text" idade="Idade">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Idade">
```

tenho essa função, nao sei se ta certa e também nao consigo vincular

```
function idade(ano_aniversario, mes_aniversario, dia_aniversario) {
    var d = new Date,
        ano_atual = d.getFullYear(),
        mes_atual = d.getMonth() + 1,
        dia_atual = d.getDate(),

        ano_aniversario = +ano_aniversario,
        mes_aniversario = +mes_aniversario,
        dia_aniversario = +dia_aniversario,

        quantos_anos = ano_atual - ano_aniversario;

    if (mes_atual < mes_aniversario || mes_atual == mes_aniversario && dia_atual < dia_aniversario) {
        quantos_anos--;
    }

    return quantos_anos < 0 ? 0 : quantos_anos;
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) ou [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia. A solucao.

```
<h2>Qual sua data de nascimento?</h2>

    <input type="text" id="dia" placeholder="Ano"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="mes" placeholder="dia"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="ano" placeholder="mes"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Idade" id="submit">

    <p id="msg"></p>


    <script>

        var ano = document.querySelector('#dia');
        var dia = document.querySelector('#mes');
        var mes = document.querySelector('#ano');

        var msg = document.querySelector('#msg')

        document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click',(e) => {

            msg.textContent = "Voce tem " + idade(ano.value,dia.value,mes.value) + ' anos';

        });

        function idade(ano_aniversario, mes_aniversario, dia_aniversario) {

            var d = new Date,
                ano_atual = d.getFullYear(),
                mes_atual = d.getMonth() + 1,
                dia_atual = d.getDate(),

                ano_aniversario = +ano_aniversario,
                mes_aniversario = +mes_aniversario,
                dia_aniversario = +dia_aniversario,

                quantos_anos = ano_atual - ano_aniversario;

            if (mes_atual < mes_aniversario || mes_atual == mes_aniversario && dia_atual < dia_aniversario) {
                quantos_anos--;
            }

            return quantos_anos < 0 ? 0 : quantos_anos;
        }

    </script>
```